# Issue with IndexIgnore htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I have project from a customer. It has an htaccess file with the following row

```
IndexIgnore */*
```

When I have that row in htaccess file, my server is not working correctly and I get Internal Server Error when running my virtual host. When I delete that row everything works correctly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName shoplocal
    DocumentRoot d:/sites/shop
    <Directory  "d:/sites/shop/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't want to change anything in the htaccess file. What setting I can change in my Apache to get this running correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my issue, I did not have my mod_autoindex turned on.

Just remove comment from this module and restart the server

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

Answer (score 0):

`IndexIgnore` is to add to the list of files to hide when listing a directory.
`IndexIgnore */*` = Empty folder listing everywhere (effect for instance: no entrance to the requested page and an error).  This makes you think your server is not correctly working, but it is working fine and doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

So you need to find out why this rule is set.  Perhaps to block access to something (or all things in your example).  And perhaps the restrictions can be handled just fine with `Options -Indexes` to block lisiting on folders without a default document (index.file).